# Python 3.6 How to fix TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes error?

Tags: python-3.x

Using python 3.6.4 and im getting this:

```
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

at this line?

```
myMessages = rMail.message_from_string(i)
```

This worked in 2.7. I tried to fix like so but clearly something is wrong?

```
myMessages = io.StringIO(rMail.message_from_string(i))
```

Comment: What contains **i** ? try **i.decode("utf-8")**

Comment: Thanks, I got it figured out:
myMessages = (rMail.message_from_bytes(i))